# check single value from one table with table with multiple values separated by comma

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in which one contains the correct answers to the questions and the other contains the answers submitted by user.

I want to calculate the correct answers the user has entered with the tables which have the correct answers and make a new column, `status`, which has the status such as 'correct' or 'incorrect'.

The problem is the correct answer tables has values separated by comma such as `a,b,c` and if a user enters the value its being send as single entry . such as `a` and then a new entry `b` . and i want to compare the values `a` and `b` present in the user answers submitted by user table to the correct answer table with entry `a,b,c` and also if a user enters a option `d` instead of `b` and `d` is not in `a,b,c` even if the user entry `a` is in `a,b,c` then also the answer should be marked as incorrect . So even if one option selected by user is wrong then the exact correct options in the correct option table then the status should be incorrect .

I have made a [SQL fiddle of the tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67fb5) against which I tried this query

```
SELECT  qa.question_id,qa.type,qa.answers
FROM    questions_answer qa, user_test_answers uta 

            where FIND_IN_SET(uta.answers, qa.answers) > 0 and qa.question_id='4' and uta.user_id='2' and qa.question_id=uta.question_id
```

This returned empty results.

The result i expect is

```
question_id  test_id  user_answer     type             correct_answer     status   
  13            4        a         multiple_choice          c            incorrect 
  13            4        c         multiple_choice          c             correct   
  14            4        a         multiple_choice          a,c           correct  
  15            4        b          true_false              a             incorrect
```

Comment: Good that you tried something and posted a fiddle, but it's also useful to see the desired result set. Of course, the proper answer is to normalize your design

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for your help regarding the confusion i had to make a correct approach to the solution via mysql . I will try to make a desired result set 1min

Comment: There are ways to do this but at the end of the day, you're doing it wrong... You should never store multiple values in one field [unless it's purely for storage not use in a query]. Use a Many-to-many relationship instead and store the fields individually. See the [2nd normal form](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)

Comment: @Strawberry Added the required result format . I guess this will help

Comment: @user1001176: Result what you have seen is correct. Because user with id `'2'` has not answered for question with id `'4'`. Hence empty resultset. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67fb5/7

Comment: @Ravinder I am trying to compare values in two tables . but it seems your are using two queries in you fiddle with select *

Comment: My attempt was first to check if they fetch any results. As they didn't fetch one, combining too wont fetch any results.

Comment: I don't understand why 'c' is the correct answer for 13. And I don't understand why (the non-normalized version of) the questions_answer table has an `answer_id`. Presumably, there can only be one answer per question with this design! And I think you meant test_id = 4, not question_id = 4 !?!

Comment: Yes it was my mistake i wrote question_id=4 its test_id=4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `GROUP_CONCAT` in `MySQL`:

```
SELECT uta.question_id, uta.test_id, GROUP_CONCAT(uta.answers ORDER BY uta.answers) AS user_answer, qa.type, qa.answers correct_answer,
CASE WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(uta.answers) = qa.answers THEN 'correct' ELSE 'incorrect' END
AS status
FROM user_test_answers uta
LEFT JOIN questions_answer qa
ON qa.question_id = uta.question_id
GROUP BY uta.user_id, uta.question_id
```

Check I used `ORDER BY` in `GROUP_CONCAT` which means that in`questions_answer` table, answers must be in alphabetical order.

Also, there seems to be an invalid entry in `user_test_answers`, with `question_id` 20.

HTH

EDIT:

```
SELECT uta.question_id, uta.test_id, uta.user_answer, qa.type,
qa.answers correct_answer,
CASE WHEN uta.user_answer = qa.answers THEN 'correct' ELSE 'incorrect' END
AS status
FROM questions_answer qa
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT user_id, type, test_id, question_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(answers ORDER BY answers) AS user_answer,
  timestamp from user_test_answers
  GROUP BY user_id, question_id
) uta
ON qa.question_id = uta.question_id
```

EDIT 2:

```
SELECT uta.question_id, uta.test_id, uta.user_answer, qa.type,
qa.answers correct_answer,
CASE WHEN uta.user_answer = qa.answers THEN 'correct' ELSE 'incorrect' END
AS status
FROM questions_answer qa
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT user_id, type, test_id, question_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(answers ORDER BY answers) AS user_answer,
  timestamp from user_test_answers
  WHERE user_id = 2 AND test_id = 4 -- for user 2 and test 4
  GROUP BY user_id, question_id
) uta
ON qa.question_id = uta.question_id
WHERE test_id = 4 -- try omitting this one in case you get incorrect results
```

IMHO, you need to look at and improve your DB design and schemas.

Comment: i tried your query in sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90902e/2 but it seems it is giving all answers to incorrect

Comment: Thank you for the answer . But you are checking questions to answers present . What if a user does not enters a answer for a question . then this can't be matched ? how do i get that to be in incorrect status ?

Comment: You are getting 'incorrect' because in the fiddle you provided every question was answered incorrectly. For your second problem, you try changing `LEFT JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN` and check if you get desired result.

Comment: changing it from LEFT JOIN to RIGHT JOIN didn't helped

Comment: Edited my answer. Tripped by `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: Nice this seems to be working . Thank you so much :) . You helped me alot . One last question How can use where user_id='2' and test_id='4' here ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Harsh . I did used that edited 2 answer but when i use it as it is then it does not shows the result for the case when a user has not entered a value and it should be shown as incorrect and when i remove the last line you said . It shows all results again regardless of specifying test id as 4

Comment: I cannot be really sure because you would need more data in tables to check it out. You have very limited data in your fiddle which makes it difficult to arrive at any solution. Table questions_answer doesn't have any attribute related to test_id, so I really cannot help you with this. I would need more information and if I assume correctly, there ought to be some table which stores what test_id has questions associated with it.

Comment: i think we need a test_id field in the correct answers table so that this system could work . can you please gimme 5mins . let me confirm this

Comment: Ok i got this . We need a extra field test_id in correct questions table too . then this code works as i thought . Thank you so much for your help Harsh . You have saved me from a big nightmare .